# Are there any resources for language independent performance tips?

Tags: performance

I work with many people that program video games for a living.  I have a quite a bit of knowledge in C++ and I know a number of general performance strategies to utilize in day to day programming. Like using prefix ++/-- over post fix.

My problem is that often times people come to me to give them tips on general optimizations they can do on a regular basis when programming, but often times these people program in all sorts of languages. Some use C++, C#, Java, ActionScript, etc.

I am wondering if there are any general performance tips that can be utilized on a day by day programming basis?  For example, I would suggest prefix ++/-- over postfix for people programming in another language, but I am just not sure if that is true.

My guess is that it is language specific and the best way to go about general optimizations is to make sure you are not using majorly bloated algorithms, but maybe someone has some advice.

Comment: Where do you work that performance is always an issue?

Comment: In my experience, database performance is always the issue.

Comment: @Ken: "always the issue"? Really? Cost, correctness, reliability, time to market, maintainability, competing goals, or support are never the issue? Never ever?

Comment: @Dour High Arch - I really should have added a smiley at the end of my comment. :) Seriously though, in most applications (that I've encountered) database and I/O performance issues far outweigh slow language issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into language specifics, or even knowing whether this is embedded, web, CAD, game, or iPhone programming, there isn't much that can be said.  All we know is that there's multiple languages involved, and for some unknown reason performance is always slower than desirable.

First, check your algorithms.  A slow algorithm can cause horrible performance.  Read up on algorithms and their complexity.

Second, note if there are any really slow operations, such as hitting a database or transmitting information or moving a robot arm.  See if the program is doing more of those than it should.

Third, profile.  If there's a section of code that's taking 5% of the time, no optimization will make your program more than 5% faster.  If a section of code is taking a lot of the time, it's worth looking at.

Fourth, get somebody who knows what they're doing to make any specific optimizations.  Test them when they're done to make sure they actually speed up performance.  When performance was an issue, I've improved it with some counterintuitive measures, like rolling up loops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can generalize optimization as such. To optimize execution time, you need to dig deep into the language and understand how things work *in detail*. Just guessing or making assumptions on experiences with other languages won't work! For example, writing `x = x << 1` instead of `x = x*2` might be a big benefit in C++. In JavaScript it will slow you down.

With all the differences between all the languages it's hard to find generic optimization tips. Maybe for some languages which are similar (f.ex. C# and Java). But if you add both JavaScript and Python to that list I'm pretty sure not many **common** optimization techniques will be left over.

Also keep in mind that premature optimization is often considered bad practice. Developer-hours are *much* more expensive than buying additional hardware.

However, there is *one* thing which comes to mind. Over the past decade or so, Object Relational Mappers have become quite popular. And hence, they emerge(d) in pretty much all popular languages. But you have to be careful with those. It's easy to load tons of data into memory that you will never use in your code if not properly configured. Keep that in mind. Lazy loading might be of some help here. But your mileage *will* vary.

Optimization depends on so many things that answering such a generic question would make this post explode into a full-fledged paper. In my opinion, optimization should be regarded on a project-by-project basis. Not only Language-by-Language basis.

Comment: If you have a decent compiler, `x = x << 1;` will be exactly the same as `x = x * 2;`.  If you have a compiler so bad that one is faster than the other, the first step in improving performance is to get a better compiler.

Comment: Since JavaScript numbers are all floating point, performing `x = x << 1` requires it to convert to an integer, shift left, and convert the result back to a double. Just multiplying by 2 is a simple operation. On a Pentium 4 the shifter was much slower than the adder, so when the compiler translates `x = x * 2` to `x = x + x` it will be an add operation that could be 8 times as fast as the shift.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split this into two separate questions:

1) Are there language-agnostic ways to **find** performance problems? YES. Profile, but [avoid the myths around that subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

2) Are there language-agnostic ways to **fix** performance problems? IT DEPENDS.

A general language-agnostic principle is: do (1) before you do (2).
In other words, Ready-Aim-Fire, not Ready-Fire-Aim.

[Here's an example of performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773), in C, but it could be any language.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I have learned since asking this:

1. I/O operations are usually the most expensive to performance.  This holds especially true when you are doing disk or network I/O (which is usually the most expensive because if you have to wait for a response from the other host you have to wait for all processing and I/O operations the remote host does).  Only do these operations when absolutely necessary and possibly consider using a cache when possible.
2. Database operations can be very expensive because of network/disk I/O and the translation time to and from SQL.  Using in-memory DB or cache can help reduce I/O issues and some (not all) NoSQL databases can reduce SQL translation time.
3. Only log important information.  Using logging libraries like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) can help because you can put logging to your hearts desire in your application but you set each message to a certain log level.  Whichever log level you set the application to it will only log messages at that level or higher.  This way if you need to troubleshoot functionality you only have to change a quick config and restart you application to give you additional messages.  Then when you are done just turn you application back to the default level so that you do not log too often.
4. Only include functionality that is needed.  Additional functionality may be nice to have but can increase processing time, provide additional locations for the application to fail, and costs your team development time that could be spent on more important tasks.
5. Use and configure your memory manager correctly.  Garbage collection routines can kill performance if they are not configured correctly.  If every minute you application freezes for a second or two for garbage collection your customer probably will not be happy.
6. Profile only after you have discovered a performance issue.  Profilers will make the applications performance look worse than it is because you have your application and the profiler running on the same host, consuming the same hardware resources.
7. Do not prematurely do performance tuning.  There are general practices you can take that should be better on performance in each language, but starting performance tuning in the middle of application development can cost you a lot on development because there is still functionality to be added.
8. This is not necessarily going to help performance but keep class dependency to a minimal.  When you get into performance tuning there is good chance you will have to rewrite whole portions of code, which if there is a lot of dependencies on the section you are performance tuning the greater chance you will break the code.  It can often be a domino affect because after fixing the performance issue than you have to fix all the dependencies, and possibly dependencies of the original dependencies.  A performance tuning exercise estimate for a few hours can quickly turn into months with an application that has a lot of dependencies.
9. If performance is a concern do not use interpreted languages (scripting languages).
10. Only use the hardware you need.  Having a system with a 64 core processor may seem cool but if you only have two or three threads running in your application than you are getting little benefit from having 64 cores.  In fact, in rare instances having overly excessive hardware can sometimes hurt performance because the chips have to be wired to handle all the hardware which can cause your application to spend more time switching between cores or processors than actually being processed.
11. Any timing metrics you report make as granular as possible.  Currently, you may only need to be worried about the number of milliseconds a process takes but in the future as you make your application faster and faster you may need more granular timings.  If version A uses milliseconds and version B uses microseconds, how can you compare performance if version B is taking about the same number of milliseconds.  Version B may be better but you just can't tell because version A did not use granular enough metrics.